# 403. That’s an error - Rate-limit exceeded That’s all we know - Image from YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-data-api, rate-limiting

I've created a website that uses the YouTube data API to get YouTube data for a chosen user. This has always worked fine for me, but the amount of traffic is now at a level that embedding YouTube images is no longer a 100% solid.

I use the YouTube Data API V3 to get the image URL of YouTube banner images, which are then added as the src attribute for an existing `<img>` element.

Because the website has pretty high amounts of traffic (mostly 500-3000 realtime users) the YouTube image servers (like this one: https://yt3.ggpht.com) started returning a 403 error when my server sends to many (image) GET requests. The error looks like this:

---

403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL https://yt3.ggpht.com/Xs3rhrNjuGoNnd6aXPdZqdfiOIp5EbvN9-PYSaP8xTY1cx6Ced5No6sHNZupNrQmsidY2W-X=w2560-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no from this server. (Client IP address: xx.xx.xxx.xxx)

Rate-limit exceeded That’s all we know.

---

From the moment this limit is exceeded, my website shows no images (from the YouTube image server) for a while and after x minutes when the exceeded limit is reset the images work again. I want to prevent this from happening, because the YouTube bannerimage is important for the UX of my website.

**My first question**: Does anyone know what the exact numbers are for this rate limit on YouTube images? How many requests can be done in X time?

**My second question**: Does anyone know a solution to prevent triggering this error and still serve YouTube images to every user?

I have some theories of my own but they would have a lot of impact on my servers:

- Since the rate limit is bound to an IP address, I could run my website on multiple IP's with some kind of load balancer.
- I could save the images to my server when it is requested for the first time as a caching mechanism. When the image would get requested again I could serve it from my own server, which prevents limits from being exceeded. To prevent updated YouTube images from not showing I would have to delete the images every X hours.

I'd rather not do this because both of these theories would have big impact on the server load.

Comment: Same problem here. I noticed that SocialBlade loads images in the same way buy without problems. I do not understand why that happens...
Any suggestion?

Comment: Edit: SocialBlade does really experience the same problem as well

Answer (score 14):

Both your theories would work in practice but as you mentioned, it's a lot of work. You can add the `referrerPolicy="no-referrer"` to your `img` tag and it should make the request without a referrer header, making the request not return a 403 anymore.

My assumption is that you, like myself were running on a local server with a popular port and Google/Youtube's image server calculates rate limits based on the `referrer` header (Although a very poor method, this seems logical based on the HTTP interaction between the image request getting a 200 VS a 403 being decided based on the `referer` header). This means everyone who is accessing YouTube channel logos using `localhost:3000` would be sharing the same rate limit due to sharing the same `referer` header value and whatever the rate limit is being exceeded. This is only my theory though as it's impossible to tell what YouTube is doing on their backend.

Comment: This was exactly my issue when accessing user avatar images as well!  It seems like it's wise to add the `no-referrer` property whenever fetching an image from Google API services.

Comment: I have the same implementation and sometimes hit this error without any idea why. I think your assumption makes sense, although as you said, we can't validate it. Your referrerPolicy attribute immediately worked. I moved one image at a time; those without the policy were still blocked. Those with the policy set showed up. Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I performed some experiments to understand better the problem.

It seems like YouTube images servers perform a kind of matching on `referer` (and probably on IP too) to limit the requests from external environments

As far as I've understood, the problem lies in HTTP `referer`. Indeed, when you experience a 403 error you can try to modify the HTTP request, changing the `referer`, and it works like a charm.

From the technical point of view, I think it is not possibile doing that via Javascript, you could set up a proxy to process all the `img` requests and change the `referer` as you like. The drawback is that all requests pass through your proxy and come from the same IP.

From the YouTube policy point of view, I do not know if that solution could be fine. Probably not (otherwise why that limitations?).